# Admob Native Advanced Not Clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, admob

I have created a custom View Class that inherits from **GADNativeContentAdView** Class. When I receive an advertisement and the delegate is called, I fill my custom view with the data as shown below.

Everything looks fine but the problem is that it is not clickable at all. I tried to set the actionbutton userinteraction to false, but still won't work.
I also tried to register using following:

> -(void)registerAdView:(UIView *)adView
>          clickableAssetViews:(NSDictionary *)clickableAssetViews
>       nonclickableAssetViews:
>           (NSDictionary *)nonclickableAssetViews;

Any idea how to get it to work?

```
- (void)setNativeContent:(GADNativeContentAd *)nativeContent
{
    self.nativeContentAd = nativeContent;
    headlineLabel.text = nativeContent.headline;
    bodyLabel.text = nativeContent.body;
    advertiserImage.image = ((GADNativeAdImage *)nativeContent.images.firstObject).image;
    [actionButton setTitle:nativeContent.callToAction forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if (nativeContent.logo && nativeContent.logo.image)
    {
        advertiserLogo.image = nativeContent.logo.image;
    }
    else
    {
        advertiserLogo.image = advertiserImage.image;
    }
    NSDictionary *clickableArea = @{GADNativeContentHeadlineAsset:headlineLabel, GADNativeContentImageAsset:advertiserImage, GADNativeContentCallToActionAsset:actionButton};

    NSDictionary *nonClickableArea = @{GADNativeContentBodyAsset:bodyLabel};

    [nativeContent registerAdView:self clickableAssetViews:clickableArea nonclickableAssetViews:nonClickableArea];
}
```

Comment: registerAdView is a new, experimental feature we're testing with just a few publishers. If you haven't already been talking with AdMob as part of a beta program, it's likely that you wouldn't be able to use it. If that's the case, the SDK should be printing something to your log.

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured out a way to make the entire native ad clickable without using a .xib. I subclassed GADNativeContentAdView and created a tappableOverlay view that I assigned to an unused asset view in its superclass. In this case, it was the callToActionView. Then I used the not-so-documented GADNativeContentAd.registerAdView() method:

```
- (void)registerAdView:(UIView *)adView
   clickableAssetViews:(NSDictionary<GADNativeContentAdAssetID, UIView *> *)clickableAssetViews
   nonclickableAssetViews: (NSDictionary<GADNativeContentAdAssetID, UIView *> *)nonclickableAssetViews;
```

Here's a Swift 4 example:

```
class NativeContentAdView: GADNativeContentAdView  {
    var nativeAdAssets: NativeAdAssets?

    private let myImageView: UIImageView = {
        let myImageView = UIImageView()
        myImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        myImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        return myImageView
    }()

    private let myHeadlineView: UILabel = {
        let myHeadlineView = UILabel()
        myHeadlineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myHeadlineView.numberOfLines = 0
        myHeadlineView.textColor = .black
        return myHeadlineView
    }()

    private let tappableOverlay: UIView = {
        let tappableOverlay = UIView()
        tappableOverlay.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tappableOverlay.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return tappableOverlay
    }()

    private let adAttribution: UILabel = {
        let adAttribution = UILabel()
        adAttribution.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        adAttribution.text = "Ad"
        adAttribution.textColor = .white
        adAttribution.textAlignment = .center
        adAttribution.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.8, blue: 0.4, alpha: 1)
        adAttribution.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold)
        return adAttribution
    }()

    override var nativeContentAd: GADNativeContentAd? {
        didSet {
            if let nativeContentAd = nativeContentAd, let callToActionView = callToActionView {
                nativeContentAd.register(self,
                                         clickableAssetViews: [GADNativeContentAdAssetID.callToActionAsset: callToActionView],
                                         nonclickableAssetViews: [:])
            }
        }
    }

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundColor = .white
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        callToActionView = tappableOverlay
        headlineView = myHeadlineView
        imageView = myImageView
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()

        addSubview(myHeadlineView)
        addSubview(myImageView)
        addSubview(adAttribution)
        addSubview(tappableOverlay)
    }

//    override func updateConstraints() {
//          ....
//    }
}
```

Just be sure to pin the `tappableOverlay` to its superview edges so that they're the same size...in `updateConstraints()`.

Comment: It seems now GADNativeContentAdView is not available in GoogleMobileAds sdk

Answer (score 1):

Inside the method simply you can create and place Ad in view hierarchy.

```
 GADNativeContentAdView *contentAdView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NativeAdView" owner:nil options:nil].firstObject;
```

After assigning the properties, associate the content Ad view with the content ad object. This is required to make the ad clickable.

```
contentAdView.nativeContentAd = nativeContentAd;
```

Comment: I do not want to use xib file, I want to create it programmatically. I have the property set "contentAdView.nativeContentAd = nativeContentAd"

Comment: hi zahr,i itself want to load ad without using xib file,did you found any solution regarding this

Answer (score 1):

Only AdMob whitelisted publishers can use the registerAdView API :)

All publishers can use xib to create an ad view.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to link **custom** GADUnifiedNativeAdView outlets to your UILabels, UIButtons and ImageViews, so GADUnifiedNativeAdView will know what to interact with
[image]

[image: These are custom outlets, drag them directly to your storyboard elements]

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was cause I created my views without xib.
In this case just set mediaView property to your GADNativeAdView

here the minimum working code

```
final class EndBannerController: UIViewController {
        
    private let adId: String
    private let adView = GADNativeAdView()
    private let mediaView = GADMediaView()
    
    private var adLoader: GADAdLoader?
    
    init(adId: String) {
        self.adId = adId
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { return nil }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        adView.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(adView)
        
        mediaView.frame = view.bounds
        adView.mediaView = mediaView
        adView.addSubview(mediaView)
        
        let loader = GADAdLoader(
            adUnitID: adId,
            rootViewController: self,
            adTypes: [.native],
            options: nil
        )

        loader.delegate = self
        
        self.adLoader = loader
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.loadBannerAd()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        adView.frame = view.bounds
        mediaView.frame = view.bounds
    }
    
    private func loadBannerAd() {
        let request = GADRequest()
        request.scene = view.window?.windowScene
        self.adLoader?.load(request)
    }
}
```